# Confusion about UpdatePanel Loading image

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I am trying to learn how to use UpdatePanel And this is my code.The problem is everything is ok but I cant see Loading.gif image  .when code excatues Its wisible  aspx page  .What am i missing out here

```
           <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <img src="load.gif" />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have trigger in `UpdatePanel` like this:

```
<Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: I have added inside update panel .But nothing chanced

Comment: I have used thread (seaerc for google from another sample)and it works I actually have no idea why is that.Any idea

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `asp:Image`:

```
<ProgressTemplate>
       <asp:Image ID="loader" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/loader.gif" />
</ProgressTemplate>
```

Comment: After adding a thread and wait 3 sn It works but I dont understand the  reason why Display ufter property didnt work and thread worked